# Print the information in one sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

print all information about an individual in one sentence as follows  "[Name] is a [Occupation] for [Number of years] years in [City],[State]."

**example input:-**

Sunil Shankar Salman

doctor dentist carpenter

15 10 10

Lucknow Delhi Mumbai

Uttar_Pradesh New_Delhi Maharashtra

**output:-**

Sunil is a Doctor for 15 years in Lucknow, Uttar_Pradesh.

Shankar is a Dentist for 10 years in Delhi, New_Delhi.

Salman is a Carpenter for 10 years in Mumbai, Maharashtra.

```
**my code** 


name=str(input())+" "
profession = str(input())+"  "
no_of_years=(input())+"  "
cities=str(input())+" "
states=str(input())+" " 

print(f"{name},is a {profession} for  {no_of_years} years  in {cities}, {states}")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822 and make sure to **ask a question**. Simply copying and pasting an assignment, and showing the code you have so far, does not make a question. We will not read your code, try it for you, decide what is wrong, and also explain how to fix it. The purpose of Stack Overflow is to build a library of questions *that other people can use with a search engine*. It is not a help desk or a discussion forum or a code-writing service.

Comment: here a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72930716/how-to-use-sep-parameter-in-format/72931897#72931897)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming there is not space between lines in input,
Store the details vertically , matrix transpose give matrix with details of person in each row. `zip()` function helps in transposing the matrix

```py
details_vertical = []
for ctr in range(5):
    details_vertical.append(input().split())
for name, profession, experience, city, state in zip(*details_vertical):
    print(f"{name},is a {profession} for  {experience} years  in {city}, {state}")
```

Comment: Please read [answer]. The answer section is for *answers* to clearly asked *questions*, not to supply code vaguely described tasks.

Comment: what if there is a space between each sentence?

Comment: @SriVishnu you mean space between lines?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to use the build-in [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format)-approach instead of the f-string: it is more versatile since you can make a template string which is shared among the data of other "people". The data per person can be collected with a dictionary comprehension which will be passed to the template. Notice the key-value expansion of the dictionary, `**`.

```
# form per person

string_template = "{name}, is a {profession} for  {no_of_years} years  in {cities}, {states}"
keys = 'name', 'profession', 'no_of_years', 'cities', 'states'

data = {k: input(f'Insert {k}: ') for k in keys}

print(string_template.format(**data)) # key-value expansion
```

To further reduce the dependency between the `keys` and `string_format` one can use (again) the string-`format` functionality:

```
# per person
keys = 'name', 'profession', 'no_of_years', 'cities', 'states'

string_template = "{}, is a {} for  {} years  in {}, {}".format(*map('{{{}}}'.format, keys))
...
```

Notice the in `{{{}}}` two brackets are needed for escape the symbol and the last for the substitution with `format`.

---

Here a possible interactive program:

```
keys = 'name', 'profession', 'no_of_years', 'cities', 'states'

string_format = "{}, is a {} for  {} years  in {}, {}".format(*map('{{{}}}'.format, keys))

data_people = []
while True:
    main_menu_selection = input('[enter] Add a person\n[q] Quit')
    if main_menu_selection == 'q':
        print('Quit.')
        break

    data_person = {k: input(f'Insert {k}: ') for k in keys}
    data_person_str = string_format.format(**data_person)
    data_people.append(data_person_str)

print(*data_people, sep='\n')
```

Comment: As I said on the other answer. there is still no clear question here, so there is no good reason to answer. This is not [codereview.se]; we aren't going to just make arbitrary suggestions about how to improve the code. It's not clear whether OP wants an interactive program, what is supposedly wrong with the existing code, or why OP needs help (and what with).

Comment: @Karl Knechtel for me is clear, or at least was it when I wrote my answer. I used the title as guideline and the rest of the information to fill the gaps