# How to use sep parameter in .format?

Tags: python

I just started learning python and I'm experimenting new things.

```
isim = input("Name:")
soyad = input("Surname:")
yaş = input("Age:")
edu = input("Education:")
gen = input("Gender:")

print("Name: {},Surname: {},Age: {},Education: {},Gender: {}".format(
                                                                isim,soyad,yaş,edu,gen))
```

My aim is to use `\n` after all brackets (`{}`) so I'll be able to print them more organised but I don't want to  use `\n` after every part.

```
print(a,b,c,d,e,sep = \n)
```

is the only way I know. I want to use `sep` and `format` together. How can I do that?

Comment: `sep` is an optional keyword argument to the built-in [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function, so using it would not apply when displaying a single value as you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

You're only printing *one* string created by using `format` so `sep` doesn't apply. You could expand a generator expression that adds `"\n"` to each argument to `format`, though.

```py
print("Name: {},Surname: {},Age: {},Education: {},Gender: {}".format(
                                        *(f"{x}\n" for x in [isim,soyad,yaş,edu,gen])))
```

You may instead wish to use a multi-line f-string, though.

```py
print(f"""Name: {isim}
Surname: {soyad}
Age: {yaş}
Education: {edu}
Gender: {gen}""")
```

Comment: There's something ironic about using an `f` string inside of a `.format` :')

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd just format your print statement like:

```
print(f"Name: {isim}",f"Surname: {soyad}",f"Age: {yaş}",f"Education: {edu}",f"Gender: {gen}", sep='\n')
# OR
print(f"Name: {isim}\nSurname: {soyad}\nAge: {yaş}\nEducation: {edu}\nGender: {gen}")
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @Chris's [comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72930743/9784436), you can simply apply replace before formatting your string:

```py
print("Name: {},Surname: {},Age: {},Education: {},Gender: {}".replace('{}', '{}\n').format(isim,soyad,yaş,edu,gen))
```

Answer (score 0):

A systematical approach which depends entirely on the type of field entries. Data stored into dictionary, then a *single* string is constructed using `format` and `join`.

```
# fields names
fields = ("Name",
"Surname",
"Age",
"Education",
"Gender")

# used a dictionary to store the input results
data = {field: input(field) for field in fields}

# key-value template
template_string = '{}: {{}}'

# add the keys
field_names = map(template_string.format, data)

# add the values (with separator ",\n")
result = ',\n'.join(field_names).format(*data.values())

# check result
print(result)
```

---

Another similar way could be to use the *"var="* property of f-strings. Requirement: the variables identifiers should be chosen properly since they will part of the final string. Side-effect: there are `=` around... if no conflicts they can be substituted with

```
Name = input("Name:")
Surname = input("Surname:")
Age = input("Age:")
Education = input("Education:")
Gender = input("Gender:")

# var= property of f-string
result = f'{Name=}\n{Surname=}\n{Age=}\n{Education=}\n{Gender=}'

# if no conflicts with = symbol
result = result.replace('=', ': ')

print(result)
```

---

How to use `format` and `sep` together? Taking as reference the approach in the question: a list is required, if no conflicts with other characters, split it at `,`:

```
# ...
result = "Name: {},Surname: {},Age: {},Education: {},Gender: {}".format(isim,soyad,yaş,edu,gen)
print(*result.split(','), sep='\n')
```